# Android studio editText turns uneditable when selectable

Tags: android, android-edittext, edit, clickable, jquery-ui-selectable

I have an EditText which I want to be editable and selectable, just like any other EditText. My theme is

```
...Light.NoActionBar
```

so I need an extra ActionBar for the Copy/Paste etc. when the text is selected.
So I use

```
editText.setTextIsSelectable()
```

and it works, but when I enable it, the textView becomes ineditable!
To make it editable again, I use the following

```
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setClickable(true);
    editText.setLongClickable(true);
```

but it doesn't help! Also, it doesn't make a difference whether I assign these tags in the .xml or in the code, I tried that...

I guess the solution is pretty simple, but the API docs and google didn't tell me how to make it editable again... It seems like noone ever had that problem before

EDIT:

xml:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/etMitspieler"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="Players"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:text="test"
android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
some constraint stuff... />
```

Comment: Show us your xml

Comment: Ok I added it! I hope it helps

Comment: I've tried your xml code. It works. I didn't changed anything inside the codebehind file. Whats around the `EditText`?

Comment: The EditText is inside a ConstraintLayout. Also, I just wanted to know this to make it possible to select the text and copy it, which I now solved by just copying the text to the clipboard programmatically. Not perfect, but it works...